Modify shipping price and tax from WooCommerce processing orders
I'm having problems implementing a code in WooCommerce orders.
I am debugging using one particular order and the "init" hook but eventually I need this to work with certain orders (coming from ebay).
My orders are arriving correctly in my back office but I am missing the VAT on the shipping line. I can't control this.
For example, my VAT total is 29.50 which is correct and that what shows on the item and also on the order shipping price. That is how it is being sent from ebay to my woocommerce installation.
I need that to be :
Shipping : 24.58
Shipping tax : 4.92
The shipping tax is 20% corresponds to my VAT rate for shipping on the woocommerce installation. That is to say, if I click on the Recalculate totals, that is what will appear if the shipping price is 24.58.
The results that I am getting is that woocommerce reverts to the original shipping price and adds the tax on that so the invoice does not correspond to what the person has paid.
I have spent several hours and days and can't find why it doesn't update to the $base_price.
add_action('init', 'update_ebay_orders', 10, 1);
function update_ebay_orders($order_id){
    // $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    $order = wc_get_order('1322743'); // For testing

    if (!$order) return;

    $created_via = $order->get_meta('_created_via', true);
    
    // Check if we've already processed this order to prevent double processing
    $processed = $order->get_meta('_ebay_shipping_processed', true);

    if (strtolower(trim($created_via)) == 'ebay' && !$processed) {
        // Set to on-hold while we make changes
        $order->update_status('on-hold');

        // Get all shipping items
        $shipping_items = $order->get_items('shipping');

        foreach ($shipping_items as $item_id => $shipping_item) {
            $original_total = (float) $shipping_item->get_total();

            // Calculate base price (£10.42 from £12.50)
            $base_price = round($original_total / 1.2, 2);

            // Calculate tax amount (£2.08)
            $tax_amount = round($original_total - $base_price, 2);

            // Directly update shipping item meta
            wc_update_order_item_meta($item_id, '_line_total', $base_price);
            wc_update_order_item_meta($item_id, '_line_tax', $tax_amount);

            // Add order note for verification
            $order->add_order_note(sprintf(
                'Livraison adjusted - Original: £%.2f, New Base: £%.2f, VAT: £%.2f',
                $original_total,
                $base_price,
                $tax_amount
            ));
        }
        // Mark as processed to prevent repeated processing
        $order->update_meta_data('_ebay_shipping_processed', 'yes');

        // Recalculate totals to update order total and taxes
        $order->calculate_totals(true);

        // Save the order
        $order->save();
        
        // Set back to processing status
        $order->update_status('processing');
    }
}


Note that the init hook has not any argument (so no $order_id function argument).
